# JSON chunked data breaking javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I have a Javascript that makes a GET request on a json service. The service is responding with a chunked data, and thus make the script fails with a

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

If I redo the request right after, the response comes full and the script works. Also, this dosen't happens in development.

I wonder if I can tell my server never to chunk the response?

Thanks.

**Edit (JS Code)**

```
xmlHttp.open("GET", uri + "?since=" + since, true);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xmlHttp.send();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {...}
```

Comment: Please share your javascript code

Comment: The browser should be hiding the transfer encoding. If it's breaking, it's because the server isn't sending the correct `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header.

Comment: @Barmar, witch Content-Transfer-Encoding shoud I use?

Comment: It should be sending `Content-Transfer-Encoding: chunked`.

Comment: @Barmar when trying to set the Content-Transfer-Encoding header, I get a Refused to set unsafe header "Content-Transfer-Encoding". Do you know what I can do?

Comment: How are you sending the data in chunked format in the first place? This is normally handled transparently by the webserver, not the application.

Comment: @Barmar can you join me @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39440/ajax-help ?